# Partial series equation for $\ln x$

Tags: summation

I was experimenting with various examples for a method of integration I am using, and I found a function that was significantly unusual enough to justify the use of the method without appearing trivial. However, my problem is that while the rest of the terms reduced cleanly, I was left the following summation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} ln(n)$$

Now, I am certain (I can say with 100% certainty, which is strange coming from me) that there are no algebraic mistakes in the earlier steps (hence their irrelevancy).

I think that this summation has no closed form (though I have absolutely no experience in proving such things so I cannot truly say); however, I would like to either confirm this or reduce the partial sum into something that doesn't involve the summation.

Comment: Sum of logs = ln(x!). If x is large you can try Stirling Approximation

Comment: $\log_b (x) + \log_b (y) = \log_b (xy) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an addendum to Sean Hill's comment. First, note that in your series, you are taking the sum from $n=0$, whereas $\ln 0$ is undefined. So there might be an error in your approach or a typing mistake in your question. Anyway, let's assume the sum starts from $n=1$.

There is a special function named the [log-gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#The_log-gamma_function). Since your series can be written as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\ln n=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}n\right)=\ln \Gamma(\lfloor x+1\rfloor)$$
as you see in the page I linked, there are several approximations and interesting properties for this function.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck you can still use the log-gamma function by the way

Comment: @polfosol but then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\ln n=\ln 0 + \ln \Gamma(\lfloor x+1\rfloor)$$ and you cannot assign a value to it (or you can assign the value 0 but this seems to me as a division by 0).